# Etymology of alipús

Tags: etimología, méxico, comida

**Alipús** is the word for booze in Mexico but I don't understand where it comes from. To me it sounds like an Arabic loanword but that's just a wild guess. So far I haven't been able to find its etymology anywhere online. The only fact I've been able to dig out so far is that there's a brand of mezcal from Oaxaca that goes by the name, Mezcal Alipús San Andrés but that doesn't suffice. Could it be a Nahuatl loan borrowing? Also, is the word known anywhere outside of Mexico? If so, does it mean the same thing there?

Comment: Interesting question. I found a blog entry about this: _"El alipús y el elíxir de garuz eran unas bebidas aromáticas que se vendían en las boticas como tónicos..."_ (Quince Uñas y Casanova Aventureros, _1945, Leopoldo Zamora Plowes), con el paso del tiempo y debido a que en muchas boticas o en tiendas se vendían bebidas alcohólicas en la parte trasera o trastienda, se fue deformando su uso hasta ser un sinónimo de "bebida espirituosa"_.
But that's not an answer for the etimology. Maybe that elixir's name was made up by those who produced it. We need a mexican.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first reference to *Alipús* I could find was from the 15th century, where it appears as a Catalan name:

> 1462, diciembre 23
>
> Al prior del convento de dominicos de Manresa, a **Sanç Alipús**, Francesc Artús, Jaume Terré, Damiana, hija de Romeu de Gamicans, o a su procurador, Arnau Angles y Jaume...
>
> - [*Catálogo de la cancillería de Enrique IV de Castilla, señor del principado de Cataluña*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Ats0hRLnpBUC&pg=PA27&dq=Alip%C3%BAs), (Lugartenencia de Juan de Beaumont, 1462-1464)
>     Jaume Sobrequés i Callicó

So it seems possible the word derives from a person's surname.

The earliest references to *alipús* as a common noun are from the 19th century:

> Muy Sr. mio: Supongo á V. impaciente por ver llegar al poeta *Roca* al puerto de salvacion: fuélo para él la botica de D, Vincente Cervantes, donde tomó un vaso de **alipús**, abrazó á sus amigos, estrechó mas ahincadamente á su querido Beristain, á quien mostró la pena que le afligia sobre toda ponderacion, y era el temor de que lo capasen los insurgentes, pues ...
>
> - [*Cuadro histórico de la revolucion de la América Mexicana, comenzada en ...*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Lj8TAAAAYAAJ&pg=RA3-PA1&dq="alip%C3%BAs") (1823)
>     Carlos María de Bustamante

> Aloja, **alipus**, ó bebida para refrescar: Sahthe.
>
> - [*Catecismo y declaracion de la doctrina cristiana en lengua otomí*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=a-lAAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA101&dq="alipus") (1826)
>     Joaquín López Yepes

These aren't very elucidating as to its origin, but give us an idea of how long it has been in use.<sup>1</sup>

Later we see it referenced disparagingly as an apothecary's concoction:

> #### COCIMIENTO BLANCO DE SYDENHAM
>
> ... Y no se pudiera aducir como razon en pro de la conservacion de esta fórmula en nuestro Códico farmacéutico, las circunstancias de ser muy usado por una parte, y por otra ser de origen extranjero, pues si fuera admisible lo primero, habria que consignar fórmulas como la del **alipus**, la del suero de caracoles con jarabe de berros, y otras mil, tan graciosas como aquella de la cual me ocupo, y que considero en el mismo rango : y para lo segundo, hay en contrario las razones aducidas por el Sr. Ibañez en sus "Observaciones á la Nueva Farmacopea Mexicana," al referirse al plan de la obra...
>
> - Puebla, Julio de 1876
> - [*El estudio, publicacion mensual de los trabajos leídos ante la Sociedad Médico-Farmacéutica de Puebla*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=5uNYAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA316&dq="alipus"), Tomo 1 (1875)

As corroborated by [Lucas' comment](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/10018/etymology-of-alip%C3%BAs#comment11817_10018)<sup>[source](http://xuravet.blogspot.com/2008/10/alips.html)</sup>:

> El alipús y el elíxir de garuz eran unas bebidas aromáticas que se vendían en las boticas como tónicos...
>
> - [*Quince Uñas y Casanova Aventureros*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=2QDmAAAAMAAJ&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=garuz) (1945)

---

**Notes:**

<sup>1. Slightly later than this we see it used in a completely different context, as a spike like tool:</sup>

> <sup>***Alipús.***—Está representado en la figura 2<sup>a</sup>, y sirve para abrir los chocolones en la roca para que entren los palos. Tiene un peso de 5 libras y se usan 8 onzas de acero en cada estremo para aguzarlas. Los hay que acaban en punta y otros á bisel.</sup>
>   [image]
>   <sup>...</sup>
>   <sup>*Pico.*—El martillo que usan los ademadores y que recibe este nombre, es de la misma forma y dimensiones que el usado para el tumbe de minerales. Ademas de servir para golpear sobre el **alipús** ó la cuña, lo usan para meter los palos que deben estar un poco forzados.</sup>
>
> <sup>- [*Memorias relativas a la esplotación de las minas en Guanajuato*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=fBgxAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA70&dq="alip%C3%BAs") (1866)</sup>

<sup>Note, others have also been curious as to its origin with little success:</sup>

> <sup>**Arcaísmo**</sup>
>   <sup>***alipús***</sup>
>   <sup>* Qué le parece, querido lector, si le ó invitamos un buen alipús? seguro sabe de que estamos hablando, ¿o no? LO Y es que alipús es uno de esos vocablos que nadie sabe de dónde salió y tampoco bay quien sepa si ya se fue, pues para algunos es un término muy común, para otros es un vocablo que sólo usaban sus abuelitos y, para otros más, fue, pues para algunos es un término muy común, para otros es un vocablo que sólo usaban sus abuelitos y, para otros más, ...</sup>
>
> - <sup>[*Algarabía, Issues 28-30*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ddMLAAAAYAAJ&q="alip%C3%BAs")</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I do not think there is an strict etimology for this. "Alipus" was just a very popular liquor trademark and therefore it is now used to refer to any type of alcoholic drink. It is something like the word aspirin.